# Replace string of line

Tags: string, replace, sed, awk

i have a file with lots of lines like that

Code:

```
randomstring | randomstring
```

and i want to remove everything until the "|".

Any ideas how to do this with sed/awk?

TIA!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
sed 's/^[^|]*.//'
```

Basically from the beginning of the line, substitute everything from the beginning till "|" with blank

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to baruch the beginning and end of the line:

```
sed -e  's/^.*\(|.*\)$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk, you can set the field separator to just about anything.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="|" }{print FS, $2}' yourfilename
```

Comment: Sth shorter with same essence: `awk -F'|' '{print $2}' filename`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
awk '{print $3}' file
```

Comment: He doesn't mean to get the third word, check the question again. He wants this: `awk -F'|' '{print $2}' file`

Comment: @ssapkota. My solution is the same as yours, except I use the default FS. That of course, is according to his sample data and assuming they are uniform across....

Answer (score 1):

For the multiple `|` in the lines:

```
astr | bstr | cstr | dstr
```

Greedy match

```
sed 's/.*|//'  < file  # will result: ` dstr`
sed 's/.*|/|/' < file  # will result: `| dstr`
```

Non-greedy match

```
sed 's/^[^|]*|//'  < file # will result: ` bstr | cstr | dstr`
sed 's/^[^|]*|/|/' < file # will result: `| bstr | cstr | dstr`
```

shorter - with the `cut` command

```
cut -d'|' -f-1   < file # will result: `astr `
cut -d'|' -f-2   < file # will result: `astr | bstr `
cut -d'|' -f2-   < file # will result: ` bstr | cstr | dstr`
cut -d'|' -f3-   < file # will result: ` cstr | dstr`
cut -d'|' -f2    < file # will result: ` bstr `
cut -d'|' -f2-3  < file # will result: ` bstr | cstr`
cut -d'|' -f2,4  < file # will result: ` bstr | dstr`
```